# How to convert Object back to its class

Tags: c#, object, casting

I have a method which return object, I need to change some value of object so I need to convert Object back to its class. But is always giving null whatever I have tried so far.

```
[HttpGet]
public Object GetProfile(string id)
    {
        try
        {
            var profileProxy = new ProfileProxy{
               ReturnMessage  = "";
             }

             return new { Profile = profileProxy };
        }
     }


    [HttpPost]
    public Object SaveProfile(JObject profile)
    {
            var profileProxy = profile.ToObject<ProfileProxy>();

                        var returnProfile = GetProfile(profileProxy.Id.ToString()) as JObject;

                        var rp = returnProfile.ToObject<ProfileProxy>();
                        rp.ReturnMessage = "New Message";
                        return new { Profile = rp };
     }
```

I am working on SaveProfile Method. But here returnProfile always giving null if I cast it to JObject.
Do any one have Idea how to cast it back to ProfileProxy class?
Thanks.

The `GetProfile(id)` returning this if not cast to anything.

```
{ Profile = {ProfileProxy} }
    Profile: {ProfileProxy}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have played a trick here, and safely modify my `GetProfile` class so now I do not need to cast the object to previous class. Here is my modified code.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public Object GetProfile(string id, string returnMessage = "")
    {
        try
        {
            var profileProxy = new ProfileProxy
                                   {
                                        ReturnMessage = returnMessage
                                   }; 

            return new { Profile = profileProxy };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.LogError();
            throw;
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public Object SaveProfile(JObject profile)
    {
                    var profileProxy = profile.ToObject<ProfileProxy>();

                    var returnProfile = GetProfile(profileProxy.Id.ToString()) as JObject;

                    return GetProfile(profileProxy.Id.ToString(), "New Message");
    }
```

I know Its just a trick and Not a professional solution, but just work in my case for time being.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the purpose of the ToObject is...

In C#, you can simply do `object o = myDerived` and `Derived d = (Derived)o` or `Derived d = o as Derived` if you care to check for a null pointer. If it doesn't work, you're inheritance chain is broken. Simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
var rp = returnProfile.ToObject<ProfileProxy>();
```

Do this:

```
if(returnProfile is ProfileProxy)
{
    var p = (ProfileProxy)returnProfile;
    //work with p
    p.ReturnMessage = "New Message";
    return new { Profile = p };
}
else
    MessageBox.Show("This doesn't seem to be the right class :'( ");
```

Comment: I don't think this will help. His problem is that `returnProfile` is null because he cannot cast the return value of `GetProfile` to `JObject`. See my answer for a possible solution...

Comment: it is giving `false`. Please see what I have return in `GetProfile` method and also what I am getting response from `GetProfile` method I have added at the end.

Comment: @RobertHegner, if that is the case, he needs to change the JObject to the ProfileProxy class (indeed as you mentioned)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var rp = GetProfile(profileProxy.Id.ToString()) as ProfileProxy;
```

instead of

```
var returnProfile = GetProfile(profileProxy.Id.ToString()) as JObject;
var rp = returnProfile.ToObject<ProfileProxy>();
```

And in `GetProfile` you need to replace

```
return new { Profile = profileProxy };
```

with

```
return profileProxy;
```

---

Or if you want to return a `JObject` from `GetProfile()` then try to change the return statement in `GetProfile()` to something like:

```
return new JObject(new { Profile = profileProxy });
```

And leave your `SaveProfile` method unchanged

---

**Third approach**

If you can't change your `GetProfile` method at all, then try the following. In `SaveProfile` instead of

```
var returnProfile = GetProfile(profileProxy.Id.ToString()) as JObject;
```

try

```
var returnProfile = new JObject(GetProfile(profileProxy.Id.ToString()));
```

And you also might need to change

```
var rp = returnProfile.ToObject<ProfileProxy>();
```

to something like

```
var rp = returnProfile["Profile"].ToObject<ProfileProxy>();
```

Comment: this is also giving null. Please see what I have return in `GetProfile` method and also what I am getting response from `GetProfile` method I have added at the end.

Comment: Ok I think I understand now that you want to return a `JObject` from `GetProfile`. Please have a look at my second edit.

Comment: I can not change return or Return Type of `GetProfile` method as it is also used in [HttpGet] by others. :(

Comment: Ok I added another approach. Does it help?